# Can there be induced current in a flat plate if i allow a magnet to oscillate above it?

Tags: electromagnetism

I know that if it is a loop induced current can be produced but what if the loop is now "non hollow" like its just a plate. I read that the plate will still oppose the magnetic flux which causes the oscillating magnet to slow down. So I was thinking that since it has the ability to slow the magnet then there should be an induced current. However what is the direction of the current? Do I just take the plate as one thick piece of wire and try finding out the direction of current?

Comment: If the plate is a conductor then the moving magnet will cause electrons to move in it: that's the definition of current. Obviously it's not the same kind of current flowing in a wire but it is current nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's consider an oscillating plate kept between 2 poles of a strong magnet.

The motion of the plate gets damped and it comes to a halt in the magnetic field.

This can be explained on the basis of Electromagnetic induction. Magnetic flux associated with the plate keeps on changing as the plate moves in and out of the region between the magnetic pols. The flux change induces ***Eddy currents***  in the plate.

***Directions of Eddy currents are opposite*** when the plate oscillates into the region between the poles and  when it when it oscillates out of the region.

The area of the plate determines the damping magnetic moment ***m = IA*** .

So if we reduce the are by making slots, the damping gets reduced and the plate oscillates more freely.

***Eddy currents are undesirable***. For example, in a transformer with a metallic core, Eddy currents ***heat up the core and dissipate electrical energy***.

Similarly, such phenomenon is ***possible with oscillating magnetic poles and a stationary plate.***